# Where to see list of programs installed via command prompt?

Tags: node.js, windows, angular-cli

I am new to windows and recently installed angular with the following steps,
- 1> Downloaded and installed Node, -2> Used npm install -g angular/cli, via command prompt. My question here is - I could see Node.js in the list of installed programs in control panel, I am not seeing angular here. I referred to the PATH environment variable where I could see path for Node.js but no path was specified for angular. Where will I be able to see the programs installed via command prompt ?

I referred google and did thorough exploration of my windows system

Comment: Angular is a library that you use with your web pages.  It's not a separate program you run from the command prompt.

Comment: I know, but my question is - I did npm install -g angular/cli on command prompt, this means installation happened via commad prompt (unlike UI where we download a software and click next-next to install it which shows up in the list of programs in control panel), how do I similarly see angular which i installed on cmd prompt by npm install -g angular

Comment: I still don't know what you're asking.  If you install something with `npm -g`, you can usually look at what is installed globally with npm with `npm -g list`.